# fontspec and textcomp

Tags: xetex, fontspec

On various sites, they recommend not loading the `textcomp`
package under XeLaTeX but to simply use the combination of
`fontspec` & `xunicode` (the latter being loaded automatically
by the former). This recommendation is based upon the fact
that `textcomp` uses the deprecated TS1 encoding.
However, when I try to typeset a symbol
from the `textcomp` package, e.g. `\textleaf`
(character 108 in the CRM font)
I receive a compilation error.

My question is: Do we still need to load the textcomp package
or is there an automated way, like `unicode-math` (for mathematical
symbols) to use these symbols without loading the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a comment which would be too long:

I am not getting any error. Could you please be more specific? What does the error say? What does your MWE look like?

In the following I print two leafs for you, which look nice and work without problems:

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
    \textleaf\faLeaf
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the problems occurs when you do not load the textcomp package (recommended on different sites as `obsolete` for XeLaTeX) and stil want to use their glyphs. May be you can manually define them in XeLaTex/Fontspec, but I lack the knowledge?

Comment: @PieterStroobants I see no disadvantage in loading that package. Works like a charm. We will have to wait for other opinions.